# Likelihood ratio to quantify the similarity between one sample with two other matched samples

Tags: t-test, likelihood-ratio, model-comparison, bayes-factors

I conducted a study with 3 conditions and N subjects. All subjects
performed all conditions once. I would like to know if the first condition
is similar to the second or third condition.

Formally, the dataset is composed of three dependent samples:
$$
D = \{ (x_{1i}, x_{2i}, x_{3i}), i = 1,...,N \}
$$
with $x_{kj} \sim N(\mu_k,\sigma)$ and there are two hypotheses/models:

- $H1: \mu_{12} = \mu_2 - \mu_1 = 0$
- $H2: \mu_{13} = \mu_3 - \mu_1 = 0$

A classical approach would be to perform two paired-t tests to compare
the first condition with the second or third condition but this would
not compare the two models directly.

To address this issue, I am thinking of computing the likelihood ratio:
$$
LR = \frac{\Pr(D|H1)}{\Pr(D|H2)} = \frac{\Pr(d_{12,i} | \mu_{12}=0)} {\Pr(d_{13,i}|\mu_{13}=0)} 
$$
where $d_{1k,i} = x_{ki} - x_{1i}$ are the differences between condition 1
and $k$. In principle, I can compute the two likelihoods by fitting the models

```
fit1 <- lm(I(x2-x1)~0, dat)
fit2 <- lm(I(x3-x1)~0, dat)
LR <- exp(logLik(fit1) - logLik(fit2))
```

Then, adapting [Kass and Raftery (1995)](https://www.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/kass1995.pdf), I would interpret

```
| LR      | Strength of evidence              |
|---------|-----------------------------------|
| < 1/150 | very strong evidence for H2       |
| < 1/20  | strong evidence for H2            |
| < 1/3   | positive evidence for H2          |
| > 3     | positive evidence for H1          |
| > 20    | strong evidence for H1            |
| > 150   | very strong evidence for H1       |
```

1)  Is the approach correct ?

2)  For this case where the two hypotheses/models don't have any free parameters, is the LR equivalent to Bayes Factor ?

3)  As extra question, can I compute the LR from the t statistic as
follows (simulations suggest that it is actually better):
$$
LR =  \frac{\Pr(m_{12} | \mu_{12}=0)} {\Pr(m_{13}|\mu_{13}=0)} = \frac{f(t_{12},N-1)}{f(t_{13},N-1)}
$$
where $f(t,\nu)$ are the density functions of the central t distribution, and
$$
t_{12} =  \frac{m_2 - m_1}{s_{12}/\sqrt(N)} \\\\
t_{13} =  \frac{m_3 - m_1}{s_{13}/\sqrt(N)}
$$
where $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$ are the sample means and $s_{12}$, $s_{13}$ are the 
standard deviations of the differences.

Comment: hypotheses $\ne$ models

Comment: Here is another way to look at the question: I have two models that predict two different results for each subject, which correspond to what I called conditions 2 and 3. I collected additional data in condition 1 where I presume that the subjects behaved as predicted by one of the two models but I don't which one. I assume that the difference between condition 1 and the correct model must be zero, which yielded my two hypotheses.  Is there a way to build a LR that tells me how much evidence for model 2 or 3 in condition 1?